# Can't center a fixed-positioned flexbox with margin: 0 auto

Tags: css, css-position, margin, flexbox, centering

I have a problem centering a fixed-postioned flexbox by using `margin: 0 auto;`. I can change position into relative to make it look like what I want, but a *fixed* one is what I hope.

Please view it on [JSBIN output](http://output.jsbin.com/pubuko), and if you'd like to [see the code](http://jsbin.com/pubuko/edit?html,css).

**HTML**

```
<header class="header l-container">
    <div class="site-title"> <a href="#" class="link">Home</a></div>
    <nav class="nav-box">
        <ul class="menu-box">
            <li><a href="about.html" class="about link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/" class="blog link">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="contact link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
/* change position into relative or fixed */

.header {
  position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}


/* some other settings below */

.l-container { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 6rem;
    max-width: 108rem;
}

.header,
.menu-box {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.header {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

  .site-title .link {
      float: left;
  }

  .menu-box .link {
      float: right;
  }




ul {list-style: none;}
li {margin-left: 20px;}
.link {font-size: 20px;}
```

Note: I'd like to center the whole  `.header` container and use flexbox to make the `.site-title` and `.nav-box` separated apart in both ends of `.header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding `left: 0` and `right: 0` to your fixed `.header`? The `max-width`, `margin` and `padding` will still be applied, but it will be positioned from the left and right.

### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yucahudeju/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I wonder if it's due to the floating properties of `div.site-title` and `nav.nav-box`. So I have to specify the `left` and `right` properties to the container (`.header`). Was that right?

Comment: @ChenghuaYang Sort-of. absolute/fixed positining remove the element from the document flow, but the default `auto` positioning leaves the element where it was.

Comment: This works, but I'm extremely curious if there's a _"cleaner"_ solution to this, if there's any (only using flexbox, I suppose). Though this is **a lot** cleaner than `left: 50%; margin-left: -XXXpx;`

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```